# Get every line that have number value greater than 0.1 from text file

Tags: php

I have a large text file witch have strings and numbers
in this format:

```
firstname 0.6 2  lastname
firstname 0.6 2.25  lastname
firstname 0.000 0.0002  lastname
```

I want to copy just the lines with double value that is greater than `0.1`
in that example i would copy the two line :

```
firstname 0.6 2  lastname
firstname 0.6 2.25  lastname
```

And save it in a file. I tried using `filter_var` function but I couldnt extract them.

```
$c = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Comment: Show us the code you have written. One line is not enough to help you debug your code

Answer (score 1):

> the lines with double value that is greater than **0.1**

The solution using `file` and `preg_grep` (to filter only matching lines) functions:

```
$lines = file("yourfile.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$result = preg_grep('/.*\b(0\.[2-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+)\b.*/', $lines);

print_r($result);
```

The output (for test input fragment):

```
Array
(
    [0] => firstname 0.6 2  lastname
    [1] => firstname 0.6 2.25  lastname
)
```

---

- `.*` - matches any character
- `(0\.[2-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+)` - ensures that the line contains float numbers greater than `0.1`.